# Why mklink /j works when manually entering but not when run using exec.Command?

Tags: go, command, mklink

If I manually run the following command in Windows, it runs fine and creates the Junction Directory.

```
mklink /j "c:\Users\userid\OneDrive - Enterprise 365\backup\C\Users\userid\test" c:\Users\userid\test
```

But, if I do it programmatically with Go, using the following code, it comes back with `Local NTFS volumes are required to complete the operation.`

```
mklink := "mklink /j \"c:\\Users\\userid\\OneDrive - Enterprise 365\\backup\\C\\Users\\userid\\test\\\" c:\\Users\\userid\\test"

cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", mklink)
out, err = cmd.CombinedOutput()
```

I've tried it a few different ways, but always getting the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by using PowerShell instead.

```
mklink := `New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path "c:\\Users\userid\OneDrive - 
Enterprise 365\backup\C\Users\userid\test" -Target c:\\Users\userid\test`

cmd := exec.Command("PowerShell", "-Command", mklink)
out, err = cmd.CombinedOutput()
```

I'm assuming the issue was the way that GoLang was sending the embedded quotes - `cmd` was interpreting them incorrectly. PowerShell seems to be a lot more 'forgiving'.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed the version for Go, you have a trailing backslash after 'test' in the OneDrive path.  This could be a subtle Windows behavior.

Another possibility - "mklink /j" requires an elevated command prompt.  If your Go script is not running in such an Admin-mode window, it cannot create a Junction Point (or a hard link to a file).

Comment: Giving the impression of asking a question instead of answering (even to careless readers) can cause downvotes, yes. It could be the cause for the one your post, I don't know. Though users who see a (non-rhetoric) quesiton in an answer post, instead of downvoting, are expected to flag it as "not an answer" in order to get it deleted by a moderator.